# What gender was the Midgard Serpent Jormungand?

Tags: norse, ragnarok

Is there any documentation detailing the gender of the Midgard Serpent Jormungand?

is it Male, Female, Both, Neither, Null, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Male.

Jörmungandr is referred to as a "he" in translations of the Prose Edda, such as (quotes, in both cases, from [this text](http://www.germanicmythology.com/ProseEdda/BRODEURPrologeandGylfaginning.html)):

> When they came to him, straightway he cast the serpent [Jörmungandr] into the deep sea, where *he* lies about all the land; and this serpent grew so greatly that *he* lies in the midst of the ocean encompassing all the land, and bites upon his own tail.

To go a step further, the use of the pronoun "he" is not incidental, the old norse text for the above line is:

> Ok er þau kómu til hans, þá kastaði hann orminum í inn djúpa sæ, er liggr um öll lönd, ok óx sá ormr svá, at hann liggr í miðju hafinu of öll lönd ok bítr í sporð sér.

Where ["hann"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hann#Old_Norse) is a male pronoun, analogous to the English "he".